# В консоль выводится ошибка почему?

Tags: javascript

```js
function sum(a){
  let sum = a;
  function count(b){
     return sum += b;
  }
  
   count.toString = function(){
    return sum;
  };
  return count;
};

console.log( sum(1)(2) );
console.log( sum(1)(2)(2) );
console.log( sum(1)(2)(2) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Текст ошибки

> Uncaught TypeError: sum(...)(...) is not a function

Указывает в чем проблема: функция, которую возвращает функция `sum` не возвращает функцию.

Из-за этого при попытке обратиться к результату, в данном случае число, как к функции и происходит ошибка.